How to implement INT40 with C?
How to implement INT40 using C language? Is it a 5-byte signed integer variable that can perform normal addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division?
#include <stdio.h>
struct INT40
{
    long long data : 40;
};
int main(void)
{
    struct INT40 my_data;
    my_data.data = 0x000000FFFFFFFFFF;
    long long other_data = 0x000000FFFFFFFFFF;
    printf("%lld\n", my_data.data);
    printf("%lld", other_data);
    return 0;
}

Can I use bit field to do this ? Can it work well ?
Currently, using int64 for operations and int40 for parsing seems to have issues with modulo operations,
But using bit fields does not.
#include <stdio.h>
struct INT40
{
    long long data : 40;
};
int main(void)
{
    long long data = 0xFFFFFF0000000001;
    data %= 256;
    printf("%lld %llx\n", data, data);
    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    struct INT40 my_data;
    my_data.data = 0xFFFFFF0000000001;
    my_data.data %= 256;
    printf("%lld %llx", my_data.data, my_data.data);
    return 0;
}

Output:
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:13:24: warning: overflow in conversion from 'long long unsigned int' to 'long long int:40' changes value from '18446742974197923841' to '1' [-Woverflow]
   13 |         my_data.data = 0xFFFFFF0000000001;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-255 ffffffffffffff01
--------------------------------
1 1
PS D:\git_rc\C\test_int40>


The output is :
-1 and
1099511627775

and, is that the correct result?

What is there exactly to implement? Just long long & 40bits.

It seems OK. Just don't forget to add LL suffix to long long literals,

@CreatorHell what are you actually trying to achieve? The size of a struct INT40 will most likely be 8 anyway.

Note that it is implementation-defined what, if any, base types other than signed int, unsigned int, and _Bool are allowed for bitfields.  Your compiler seems to be accepting long long in that role, but others might not, so that's a compatibility issue that might matter to you.

you may need __attribute__((packed)) or similar attributes to get an actual 40-bit struct

I want to use INT40 in STM32F405RGT6, and my product needs to send data outward through a serial port. Party A requires the INT40 data type.

I'm doubtful that even __attribute__((packed)) or similar would help here, @phuclv.  It's not the size of the bitfield itself that matters, but that of the ASU in which it resides, and I think you're unlikely to find a modern machine that would use an ASU smaller than 64 bits for the OP's 40-bit bitfield (among those that accept it at all).

_BitInt(40) (C23) could perhaps be an option. _BitInt(40) bi = (_BitInt(40)) 0x000000FFFFFFFFFF; - It'll most probably have sizeof 8 anyway, but it's a nicer type.

@CreatorHell: If you just need to send a 40-bit integer, use any wider type to calculate the value and then send its low 40 bits. That is a lot easier than if you need to create a type that fully supports 40-bit arithmetic and other semantics. If you do not know how to do that, you could ask a specific question for that. Do you really need to support all arithmetic in a 40-bit type?

In fact, I have considered this method. Perform operations according to int64 and parse according to int40. I'm just not sure if this operation is consistent with the actual INT40 operation.
For example. 0xFFFFFF0000000001 is -1099511627775 in int64 and 1 in INT40 But they modulo 256 and perform int64 operations to obtain values of -255, while the latter performs int40 operations to obtain 1

@CreatorHell You (or "party A") need to specify how the INT40 type is supposed to represent negative values.

How can 0xFFFFFF0000000001 be 1 in INT40?  There are (at least) 64 bits!  But that assertion makes me think that your issue may be with data exchange, especially including endianness, not so much with the actual representation on the local side.  On the other hand, if you take just the 40 least-significant bits then, yes, you get 1.

Yes, what I said is, according to the previous brother's statement, use a wider data type (int64) to send the lower 40 bits of data.

@CreatorHell you just need to do sign extension if it's a signed type: (value << 24) >> 24, or use this bitfield trick. Now the math is done in all 64-bit, and only do 40-bit conversion on transmission

@phuclv You're right, it works well on my stm32s.Thank you!

Generalities
I take

that can perform normal addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division

as meaning that you want a type that works with the standard +, -, *, and / arithmetic operators.  In that case, you cannot "implement" anything new, because C does not have operator overloading.  You need to work with what C already provides.
In that case, if by

a 5-byte signed integer

you mean a data type with a storage size of exactly 5 bytes, with no additional padding, then you are probably out of luck.  Although it's not out of the question, I do not anticipate that you will find this an any modern C implementation.
Bit fields
Provided that your C implementation supports a wide-enough bitfield base type, the approach presented in the question will get you an integer with 39 value bits and one sign bit, or possibly an unsigned integer with 40 value bits.  Variants could get you either definitely signed (using one of the 40 bits as a sign bit) or definitely unsigned.  That appears to be working for you, with the signed integer alternative.
But storage for bitfields is allocated inside an "addressible storage unit" that is likely to match the size of one of the implementation's built-in integer types, and on modern systems that's usually going to mean a 64-bit ASU for you. Moreover, it will vary from implementation to implementation which 40 bits of that ASU contain the value, and how they are ordered.  You need to be concerned with that when it comes to exchanging values over the serial link you described.
Bit-precise integer types
In C2X, there will be "bit-precise integer types", and I'm sure you could find a compiler that already implements these.  They allow more explicit expression of integer types with exactly-specified numbers of value bits, but although this is cleaner than bitfields, it's not much better for your purposes with regard to storage size.  I anticipate that such types will often be represented with padding, so that although a _BitInt(40) has 39 value bits and one sign bit, it is likely also to have 24 bits of padding, for a storage size of 64 bits.  And again, there is no specification for which bits are padding, or what the order of the bits must be.
Alternative: just use 40 bits
Provided that the wanted INT40 type uses two's complement representation (or is unsigned) you can probably just use a wider unsigned integer type, and consider only the least-significant 40 bits significant, but there are some caveats:

When transferring in from INT40, you will need to perform appropriate sign extension.

For binary +, -, and * operations, unary -, autoincrement and autodecrement, left shifts, and bitwise operators, you can just perform ordinary arithmetic, but

For most other operations (/, %, !, right shifts, equality operators, assignment operators, some casts) you will need to first manually mask off the  bits more significant than the 40th and then perform sign extension.

For relational operators, you will need not only to mask and sign-extend, but also to explicitly perform signed compararisons.  (The explicit signed comparisons could be avoided if you used a signed container type, but that has other complications.)

You will also need to mask and perform sign extension if you want to pass the logical INT40 value to functions, such as printf.


If your INT40 were an unsigned type than the sign extension and sign-aware relational operators described above would be mooted, but you would still need masking where indicated.
Altogether, I think this probably does not meet your requirement of being able to perform "normal" arithmetic operations.
Overall
If you cannot rely on C2X features and you want no-hassle usage of substantially all C operators, then the bitfield approach is your best bet. But as already described, it will probably get you only a logical 40-bit size, not an actual 40-bit storage size.  You will need to account for that when you transfer data to the external device.

This question certainly does not deserve the harsh criticism it gets in the comments: bit-precise signed and unsigned integer type were not fully supported in the C Standard due to implementation defined behavior in bit-fields, especially regarding signedness and for types other than int.
The upcoming C23 Standard does offer a solution for your purpose: the types _BitInt(40) and unsigned _BitInt(40) which are bit-precise signed and unsigned integers with exactly 40 bits (including the sign bit for the signed version).
Furthermore, values of this type will not be affected by the usual integer promotion rules:

6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
a _BitInt operand of a binary operator is not always promoted to an int or unsigned int as part of the usual arithmetic conversions. Instead, a lower-ranked operand is converted to the higher-rank operand type and the result of the operation is the higher-ranked type.

So if you can find a compiler that comforms to this standard, you could write:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef _BitInt(40) INT40;

int main(void) {
    INT40        my_data = 0x000000FFFFFFFFFF;
    long long other_data = 0x000000FFFFFFFFFF;
    printf("%w40d\n", my_data);
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)my_data);
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)(INT40)other_data);
    printf("%lld\n", other_data);
    return 0;
}

And see this output:
-1
-1
-1
1099511627775

clang on my macbook compiles the above code but the C library does not support the w length modifier and the output is:
w40d
-1
-1
1099511627775


Thank you for your answer, but I can only use KeilV5's C compiler, which supports up to C99.
